# Passing parameter from view to controller when button is clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created my own extension as:

```
public static MvcHtmlString hSearch(this HtmlHelper helper, string labelName, string labelCaption, string textName, string textValue, string tableName, string buttonId, 
        string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {            
        var textbuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        textbuilder.MergeAttribute("id", textName);
        textbuilder.MergeAttribute("name", textName);
        textbuilder.MergeAttribute("value", textValue);
        textbuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));


        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(labelName, helper.ViewData);
        String innerText = labelCaption ?? (metadata.DisplayName ?? (metadata.PropertyName ?? labelName.Split('.').Last())); 
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText)) 
        { 
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty; 
        }
        TagBuilder labelbuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        labelbuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(labelName)));
        labelbuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        labelbuilder.SetInnerText(innerText);            

        //return new MvcHtmlString(textbuilder.ToString());
        var buttonBuilder = new TagBuilder("button");
        buttonBuilder.MergeAttribute("id", buttonId);
        buttonBuilder.SetInnerText(buttonId);

        var formBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        formBuilder.Attributes.Add("action", urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));

        formBuilder.Attributes.Add("method", "Post");

        formBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        formBuilder.InnerHtml = labelbuilder.ToString() + textbuilder.ToString() + buttonBuilder.ToString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(formBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

I used the extensions in view as:

```
 @Html.hSearch("lblSrch", "Company", "companyName", (string)TempData["cName"], "CHComp", "Search", "Fetch", "Home", null, null)
```

Now I want to pass tableName when I click the button to the controller.. my controller looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Fetch(string search, string tablename)
    {
        var c = cbo.fetchData(search, tablename);
        return PartialView(c.ToList());
    }
```

Waiting for reply.. Thanks..

Comment: `//codes` doesn't help us. That method is obviously the bulk of your code.. can you show it to us (hSearch that is..)

Comment: What `hSearch` actually do? What button you are talking about? What view does `Fetch` action return?

Comment: This is awfully bulky code for something that can be put into a PartialView with minimal effort (and reused..). Is there a reason you've created a HtmlHelper instead of a Partial View?

Comment: I just wanted to create this for searching data from different tables in the database so that i can reuse this code in all of my programs..

Comment: @Mohayemin: Fetch View returns a webgrid view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us the code for your helper, but at a guess it writes out a label, a text field (textName), and a button. If this is the case, it will post / get `companyName=someValue` via HTTP back to your controller.

You would typically need to add a `FormCollection` to your controller if the fields are dynamically sent from the view. Alternatively, why not keep the name of the text search input static, e.g. `name="search"`, which will bind to your controller's parameter of the same name.

**Edit**
You can pass tableName back to the controller in a hidden field (`<input type='hidden' name='tableName' value='{tableNameGoesHere}'`)

But as per above, your search string will have different names- the model binder isn't going to recognise it as `string search`.

Comment: I don't want to sent the value of search to the controller, rather I want to send the textbox value plus table name to the controller at a time when i click the button. Could you suggest me a better way.. All I have in my view is a label, a textbox and a button..